# Git from Gradle: fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything

Tags: git, ubuntu, gradle

I'm stuck on a very weird issue. When performing a release with Gradle, we automatically get the version from the tags with:

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=0
```

The above command gives us the latest tag from git. It works perfectly, except for when it is run from Gradle, we get the following error:

> fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.

So from the same command line, if I run `git describe --tags --abbrev=0` it works, but if I run `./gradlew release` it doesn't work. I don't understand what is different about how gradle runs the git command that makes it not work. I've already checked that it is executed from the same directory with the same user.

For a bit of extra context, I'm working on updating our CI, from using an old CentOS 7 based image to using an Ubuntu based image. It works fine on the old image, which is all the more confusing.

If anyone has an idea about what could cause this and how to fix it, I would be very grateful.

Here's the Gradle code for reference:

```
    def output = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags', '--abbrev=0'
        standardOutput = output
    }
    return output.toString().trim()
```

Comment: Try specifying 'HEAD' as last argument (which should be the default, but maybe it helps)

Comment: Does Gradle do anything suspicious here such as export an odd `GIT_DIR` setting?